# Excluding date range in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime

I have table with year, month and dates to be excluded like shown below

```
Year | Days                 | Month | Id
-----+----------------------+-------+----
2017 | 25,26,27,28,29,30,31 | 12    | 1
2018 | 1,2,3,4              | 1     | 2
```

I am trying to exclude dates using below query, but getting an error saying varchar to int conversion error

```
Select * 
From Sample_Table st 
Inner Join Exclude_Table et On et.id = st.id 
Where st.day Not In (et.days)
```

Comment: You need to convert your "list" to real date values. Try looking into `string_split()` and `datefromparts()`. `cross apply` will be useful as well.

Comment: You fell victim to one of the [classic blunders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWW6aDpUvbQ) - the most famous of which is "never get involved in a land war in Asia" - but only slightly less well-known is this: "Never put csv values in a table column!"

Comment: Never store comma-separated strings when you are interested in their separate parts. This said, replace your table. All you need is an exclude table containing a single date column (i.e. with one row per excluded date). With such a proper table, querying will get very simple. BTW: Your query, if its syntax worked, would ignore the year and month. Is this on purpose? If so, why do you store year and month at all?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - i was using polybase approach to get the show data in table , where the table in azure datawarehuse is directly pointing to csv file in blob storage . Data is csv is accesed by SQL queries .

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - Thanks for the suggestions , The requirement was to  exclude the dates from 25th Dec to 31st Dec and 1st Jan to 4th Jan of every year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses `string_split()`  and `not exists`:

```
select * 
from sample_table st 
where not exists (
    select 1
    from exclude_table et
    cross apply string_split(et.days, ',')
    where et.id = st.id and st.date = datefromparts(et.year, et.month, value)
)
```

This assumes that `sample_table(date)` stores an actual `date` datatype (or the-like).

If you are running SQL Server < 2016, where `string_split()` is not available, an alternative uses string functions:

```
select * 
from sample_table st 
where not exists (
    select 1
    from exclude_table et
    where 
        et.id = st.id 
        and et.year = year(st.date)
        and et.month = month(st.date)
        and concat(',', et.days, ',') like concat('%,', day(st.date), ',%')
)
```

Note that both these solutions are basically workarounds for your broken design. You should have a separate table to store the exclusion dates of each `id` (either as a list of dates or as of ranges).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and workaround, I will better go with a separate table with list of dates to be excluded .